# Installation Issue with Pixar USD on macOS High Sierra

Tags: python, boost, macos-sierra, gltf, usdz

**Description**

I am following the installation documentation - https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD#getting-and-building-the-code on my macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 but after the installation is complete - I am getting a segmentation fault: 11. I also followed the suggestions of changing the build_usd.py file for crash related issues from here: https://github.com/TimvanScherpenzeel/gltf-to-usdz-research#development and switching to xcode-beta version - it does solve the crashing problem as reported there but results into another issue of segmentation fault: 11. I am also attaching the log report generated for reference at the bottom.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Switch to xocde-beta version as pointed out here - 
   https://github.com/TimvanScherpenzeel/gltf-to-usdz-research#development
2. change the build_usd.py files as pointed out in the same link as in the 
   above point.
3. Run the script as pointed out here - 
   https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD#3-run-the-script
4. After installation is complete, run the command -

   > usdview extras/usd/tutorials/convertingLayerFormats/Sphere.usda
   >   as pointed out here https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD#4-try- 
   >   it-out
5. Segmentation fault: 11 will show up with python crash report

**System Information**

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Pastebin link to the crash report - https://pastebin.com/CynSM9ek

Comment: Don't use pastebin to link relevant info. [edit] your question instead to include the relevant info inline. That said, you don't really intend to program, do you? This is rather a bug report for the software you mention and you are rather a user than a developer, right? In that case, you should file an issue in the program's bugtracking system (i.e. at github's). If you really want to develop that program, your question is still not yet on-topic, because you would first have to extract a [mcve] from the sources.